# Tableau Map Line Graph - change linking order of data points

Tags: dictionary, tableau-api

I have data with lat/lon attributes that I'm plotting onto a map. I then use the "line" mark to link the data points. It seems to automatically order them by the latitude attribute, which happens to bring two of my data points out of order: [image: see screenshot attached]
How can I manually change the order of the linking?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a path shelf in Tableau, details of the usage can be found here:
http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/using-path-shelf-pattern-analysis

You just need to create a dimension and give each coordinate of your path a running number. Once you drop that dimension on the path shelf, Tableau will use it to determine the order of the coordinates.

Comment: Thanks! I had found the tutorial you linked to earlier, but failed to implement it for some reason. It worked on second try. While still not ideal (this solution requires some data pre-processing I wanted to avoid), it's better than what I had before.